# Reading DWG file in Python and extracting edge points

Tags: python, autocad, data-extraction, cad, dwg

I have a DWG file in which I have a rectangle with several lines in it (e.g. floor plan with interior walls). How can I use Python to extract the edges (X,Y Coordinates)? I need to extract the floor plan as a graph with nodes and edges defined. So as an instance for one rectangle I should have 4 X,Y coordinates defining the edges of this rectangle as a graph.

Comment: Did you consider [EWS](http://www.devdept.com/eyeshot/webservice) to do a DWG to XML conversion, then parse the XML to extract XY coordinates?

Comment: EWS is not free.

Comment: You could save the dwg as a dxf, then read the data from the dxf, autocad offers documentation on how dxf can be read and written